# How can I debug TypeScript packages in NextJS using VSCode debugger when using transpilePackages?

Tags: next.js, vscode-debugger, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I've got a NextJS project that I'm using with Yarn workspaces in a mono repo.

Here's an example folder structure of my repo

```
- package.json
- tsconfig.json
- packages/
    - projectA
        - index.ts
        - package.json
        - tsconfig.json
- CLIApp
    - package.json
    - tsconfig.json
    - index.ts
- NextJSApp
    - package.json
    - next.config.js
    - tsconfig.json
    - pages
        - index.ts
```

When running the VScode debugger in the `CLIApp`, I am able to hit debug points in the package. When debugging the `NextJSApp` I'm able to hit debug points in the `NextJSApp` but not in the packages.

In the `next.config.js` I'm using the new `transpilePackages` option to include the `projectA` package. `transpilePackages: [ "projectA"]`

I suspect the problem is to do with the `transpilePackages` option in NextJS. Has anyone been able to get this working before?

I've tried different compilation options in `projectA` in the tsconfig.json file. But I haven't had much luck I suspect the problem is to do with the debugger settings, because of the way NextJS compiles the modules it's not linking them as internal dependencies that can be debugged.

Comment: For anyone who finds this I've gone back to the old npm package `next-transpile-modules` it seems to have better TypeScript support.